# Use mod_rewrite to change directories to variables... does this work?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

If I have a link, for example: dashboard/xyz/fff/ and I use modrewrite to change it to dashboard/?loc=xyz&action=fff when the page loads are loc and action available as variables to use?

If so, then here's a specific example I can't seem to get to work.  My rule as it sits:

```
RewriteRule ^getclients/([a-z\-]+)$ /dashboard/?action=getclients&module=$1
```

And the link that is sending them to that url:

```
<li><a href="getclients/seoanalysis" title="SEO Analysis">SEO Analysis</a></li>
```

I want now to be at .com/dashboard/?action=getclients&module=$1 and use those variables to load the page content that's needed.

However: Now the page redirects to what I believe is the "right page" but the CSS is all broken.  I only have plain text.  Feel free to suggest another way to achieve the same effect as well perhaps using jQuery and Ajax or something to load up sections of the site.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this work? If yes then what is the question here?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't clarify.  No - it is not working.  It currently, as it is, takes me to what I believe to be the right page, but none of the CSS is loading and the page is all plain text.

Comment: try `echo $_GET['action'];` and `echo $_GET['module'];` and see what you get

Comment: You probably need to change all your links from relative to absolute

Comment: It echos the variables successfully... so why are all the CSS style sheets not loading is the new question.  The echos are in the index file, so it's successfully loading the page and all the content, just not styled.

Comment: @BrendenClerget What is the css path in the index file?

Comment: href="css/mini.php?files=reset,common,form..." and it names off a bunch of CSS files that a php file consolidates and loads.  That css directory is in dashboard/css/filename.css

Comment: try loading the css files (css/mini.php) directly in the browser using the absolute path

Comment: I just noticed, if I go to view source--> click an image on a page that it's redirecting to, it's trying to find the image in the /getclients/ directory.  Example: home.com/dashboard/getclients/image.png instead of dashboard/image.png

Comment: Yes - that works to load the css, but the static images are still looking for relative paths... I don't want to go change every single image to an absolute path.  Isn't it less clean/less desirable to use absolute paths like that?  Why is the server looking for the images in the /getclients/ directory instead of the normal directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use absolute paths, you can try rewriting the requests for images, javascript, and css. Maybe something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^getclients/(.+)$ /dashboard/$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the file locations are exact, or the server might send the data from the wrong relative directory.

Answer (score 1):

For loading css, images, js files properly from a different relative path you should specify a [base URL](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp) for all relative URLs on a page like this:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/dashboard/" />
```